# Is it possible to unsubscribe a user using a rest API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, unsubscriber

I would like to unsubscribe a user using a Rest and not SOAP API, do you know if this is possible?

Thanks,
Felipe

Comment: it currently isn't possible unfortunately; https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/233543/54076

Comment: I solve it with SSJS https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_unsubLogUnsubEvent.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved by using SSJS (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_unsubLogUnsubEvent.htm)